# How to get all items list on NetSuite?

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am just starting with NetSuite and trying to pull all items with details using Restlet. With some research, I am able to pull all the items but the way I am doing now is not straightforward. I first pull the all ids of item using nlapiSearchRecord and loop through each id to get details of each item using nlapiLoadRecord and added to array. This way, it is taking to much time. Is there other way to pull all items with their details? Below is my code.

```
function getAllIDs() {
    return nlapiSearchRecord('item', null, null, null);
 }

function getRecord() {
    var all_IDs = getAllIDs();
    var len=all_IDs.length;
    var result =new Array();

  for(var i=0;i<all_IDs.length;i++) {
    if(all_IDs[i].getRecordType()==="inventoryitem")
        result[i]=nlapiLoadRecord(all_IDs[i].getRecordType(),all_IDs[i].id)
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use what @Krypton suggested but you will always get 1000 results at max.

Try following if you have requirement to get more than 1000 (using Suitescript 2.0):

```
    var columns = [];
    var filters = [['isinactive', 'is', 'F']];
    columns.push(search.createColumn({ name: "itemid"}));
    columns.push(search.createColumn({ name: "displayname"}));
    columns.push(search.createColumn({ name: "salesdescription"}));
    columns.push(search.createColumn({ name: "baseprice"}));
    var inventoryitemSearch = search.create({
        type: search.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM, //Change the type as per your requirement
        filters: filters,
        columns: columns
    });
    var arrResults = [];
    var count = 1000;
    var startIndex = 0;
    var endIndex = 1000;
    var resultSet= inventoryitemSearch.run();
    while (count == 1000) {
        var results = resultSet.getRange(startIndex, endIndex);
        arrResults = arrResults.concat(results);
        startIndex = endIndex;
        endIndex += 1000;
        count = results.length;
    }
    log.debug({title: 'arrResults ', details: arrResults });
```

Comment: Thanks it is what I actually needed. I want to add one more question. As of now I only have items less than 1000. so I could not test if it works for more than 1000 values. you are sure that using getRange we can retrieve more than 1000 data?

Comment: getRange returns the value from range specified with max of 1000. In while loop we try and concatenate each 1000 result.

Comment: Do you know if such resultSet limits exist in the N/query module too? I don't see any `getRange` function for the query module, only search. I was planning on implementing this in the query module instead of search for consistency with the rest of my scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the details you want in the search.  So, for example, you can include an `nlobjSearchFilter` so that the search only returns inventory items, and add an `nlobjSearchColumn` for each field you want to see in the details.  This way all the details you want to see are returned with the search and you can loop through the results to do what you want with them without loading every record individually - which will be where most of the performance hit is happening.

An example:

```
var inventoryitemSearch = nlapiSearchRecord("inventoryitem",null,
[                                  
   ["type","anyof","InvtPart"]
], 
[
   new nlobjSearchColumn("itemid",null,null).setSort(false), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("displayname",null,null), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("salesdescription",null,null), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("baseprice",null,null)
]
);
```

Then you can loop through the results to get details:

```
var name, displayName, description, price;
for ( var i = 0; inventoryitemSearch != null && i < searchresults.length; i++ ) {
    var searchresult = inventoryitemSearch[ i ];
    name = searchresult.getValue( 'itemid' ); 
    displayName = searchresult.getValue( 'displayname' ); 
    description = searchresult.getValue( 'salesdescription' ); 
    price = searchresult.getValue( 'baseprice' ); 
}
```

There is a lot to learn about scripted searches in NetSuite, so I'd recommend starting [here](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/29250) (NetSuite login required) and follow the links and keep reading / experimenting until your eyes glaze over.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please suggest me any link or idea to use suitscript 2.0 for restlet API. When using suitscirpt 1.0 and deploying it I used to get API endpoint. But now if I use suitscript 2.0 there is no endpoint after I deploy it.

Comment: You may find something useful at [SuiteAnswer id #43797](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43797).  If not, it would be best to ask a new question and include your script and the deployment steps you used.  HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I just like to use a generic function that accepts a search object...

```
const getAllResults = searchObj => {
try {
  const Resultset = searchObj.run()
  const maxResults = searchObj.runPaged().count
  let ResultSubSet = null
  let index = 0
  const maxSearchReturn = 1000
  let AllSearchResults = []

  do {
    let start = index
    let end = index + maxSearchReturn
    if (maxResults && maxResults <= end) {
      end = maxResults
    }
    ResultSubSet = Resultset.getRange(start, end)

    if (ResultSubSet.length === 0) {
      break
    }
    // we could intriduce a record processor to lighetn up the load
    AllSearchResults = AllSearchResults.concat(ResultSubSet)
    index = index + ResultSubSet.length

    if (maxResults && maxResults == index) {
      break
    }
  } while (ResultSubSet.length >= maxSearchReturn)

  return AllSearchResults

  } catch (e) {
    log.error(`getAllResults()`, `error : ${e}`)
  }
}
```